# SQL issue with SELECT WHERE subquery in a CASE WHEN statement

Tags: mysql, subquery, case, where-clause, mariadb-10.5

I'm trying to classify my SKU's and I'm almost there. The desired outcome is:

| product_id | sku | sku_class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CSs22-01 | sample |
| 2 | CSs22-02 | sample |
| 3 | CS2201 | cask |
| 4 | CS2202 | project |
| 5 | CS2202/A | project-cask |
| 6 | CS2202/B | project-cask |
| 7 | CS2203 | cask |

I do get `sample`, `cask`, and `project-cask` right BUT I don't get `project` right (instead I get an incorrect `cask`).

The query I'm currently using is:

```
SELECT 
     pa.product_id
    ,pm.sku
    ,(CASE 
        WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'CSs%-%' THEN 'sample'

        WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'CS%/A'
          OR pm.sku LIKE 'CS%/B'
          OR pm.sku LIKE 'CS%/C'
          OR pm.sku LIKE 'CS%/D'
          OR pm.sku LIKE 'CS%/E' THEN 'project-cask'

        WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(sku) FROM wp_wc_product_meta_lookup 
                    WHERE sku LIKE pm.sku + '%' ) > 1 THEN 'project'

        WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'CS%' THEN 'cask'
    END) AS sku_class
FROM wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup AS pa
LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup AS pm ON pa.product_id = pm.product_id
GROUP BY pa.product_id;
```

But my `WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(sku) FROM wp_wc_product_meta_lookup WHERE sku LIKE pm.sku + '%' ) > 1 THEN 'project'` is failing and results in (MariaDB) errors like:

- Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'CS2202'
- Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '%'

When I hardcode `'CS2202%'` in the WHERE statement I see -logically- all casks as projects as CS2202 is indeed a project. So the issue is with the `LIKE pm.sku + '%'` part.

How do I get that part working with the SKU from the main query?

*P.S. The logic to tag a SKU as a project is when CSxxxx% occurs more than 1 time otherwise it's a single cask.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `pm.sku + '%'` is the problem. Use CONCAT like this:

```
WHERE sku LIKE CONCAT(pm.sku, '%')
```

`+` it's not used for concatenation in MySQL

Comment: Thanks. I actually had that before and changed it to the + construction. I now changed it back to the CONCAT and that avoids the errors from being produced, so that is a win. 
However, it still results in ```cask``` instead of ```project``` for those SKU's which are a project... Any idea what else I could try to get it working?

Comment: My bad, I flipped around the last 2 WHEN statements #facepalm

Thanks it's working now!!